# Graphically closing hypothesis in formal logic

Tags: logic, logicproof

I am writing some notes for my students. I am facing a small problem. I want to write down some examples of formal logic in which open hypothesis are closed at some point, which is graphically represented by vertical lines. See the figure as reference.
[image: small example]
The example shows that, assuming the proposition in line 1, the proposition in line 7 can be proven, for which lines 1 to 7 are a proof. In the example, lines 1, 2 and 3 have a horizontal line in front, which means they are hypothesis that have been "opened" (introduced) at some moment. The later two have been "closed" with lines 6 and 5 respectively (first line 3 with line 5, and then line 2 with line 6). Note that lines are closed in a FILO manner, therefore they can't cross.

My problem: How to draw these lines? I would say pgf/tikz, but perhaps there is something simpler.

Thanks!

```
\[ \begin{array}{rll}
1&p\lthen q\\
2&q\lthen r\\
3&p\\
4&q & \mathrm{E}{\lthen}\ 1,3\\
5&r & \mathrm{E}{\lthen}\ 2,4\\
6&p\lthen r & \mathrm{I}{\lthen}\ 3{-}5\\
7&(q\lthen r)\lthen (p\lthen r) & \mathrm{I}{\lthen}\ 2{-}6
\end{array} \]
```

Update: The package [logicproof](https://ctan.org/pkg/logicproof) offers a nice classical environment for such proofs.

Comment: https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do it with Ti*k*Z. Notice that you may (temporarily) need to download `tikzmark` from [GitHub](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark) (or just hit return in the first run when there are error messages) until the updated library makes it to CTAN.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\lthen\to
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\newcounter{lconnect}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{array}{rll}
\tikzmarknode{1}{1}&p\lthen q\\
\tikzmarknode{2}{2}&q\lthen r\\
\tikzmarknode{3}{3}&p\\
\tikzmarknode{4}{4}&q & \mathrm{E}{\lthen}\ 1,3\\
\tikzmarknode{5}{5}&r & \mathrm{E}{\lthen}\ 2,4\\
\tikzmarknode{6}{6}&p\lthen r & \mathrm{I}{\lthen}\ 3{-}5\\
\tikzmarknode{7}{7}&(q\lthen r)\lthen (p\lthen r) & \mathrm{I}{\lthen}\ 2{-}6
\end{array} \]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,lconnect/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
/utils/exec=\stepcounter{lconnect},insert path={(#1.west)--
++(-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/lconnect/offset}-1*\number\value{lconnect}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/lconnect/step},0) |- (#2.west)}},
self close/.style={insert path={(#1.north west) --
++(-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/lconnect/offset}-1*\number\value{lconnect}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/lconnect/step},0) |-
(#1.south west) }}, lconnect/.cd,
offset/.initial=0.1em,step/.initial=0.4em]
 \draw[lconnect/.list={3 and 5,2 and 6},self close/.list={1,7}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, it works! However, it is missing the opening in line 1. Adding "1 and 1" to the list seems to do the work. What would you suggest otherwise? Sometimes it is useful to close a line on itself. Thanks anyway for the great answer.